# Get Highest and Lowest get_term_meta() value from Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have a Taxonomy and it named "synagogue". I made this query:

`$synagogue_terms = get_terms( 'synagogue', array('hide_empty' => false));`

Here two Term fields `lat` and `lang`, which is Lattitude and Longitude.

I need Highest and Lowest data for both `Lattitude` and `Longitude`.

I've made the query like this:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($synagogue_terms as $term){
  $name = $term->name;
  $lat = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'lat', true );
  $lang = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'lang', true );
  $items[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
} 
return $items;
```

I can't figure out how I can get those values with get_term_meta() function.

Any help will be appretiated.
Thanks

Comment: How are you adding/saving the fields?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I need help to retrieve data. Those are Taxonomy data, so adding/saving is no problem.

Comment: If trying to find out if you’re using ACF or something.  Are you just using update_term_meta()? What’s not working exactly?

Comment: Okay, i'm not using ACF. On Database table `wp_termmeta`, fields are saving on `meta_key` column. Fields are saving with ID and Value. I need to Find out the Highest `lat` and `lang` value from the meta Key. Hope I make you clear.